# Override/clear g++ default search path for libraries

Tags: linux, cmake, g++, cross-platform

### Question

I want to override/clear g++ default search path for libraries, so that g++ does only search libraries under paths explicitly specified:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --print-search-dirs | grep libraries:
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-lin
ux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/:/usr/l
ib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/arm-linux
-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnuea
bihf/lib/../lib/:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/../l
ib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/../li
b/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/
:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

Can this be done?

### Background

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 compiling c++ code for several cross-platform distributions.

I've installed Ubuntu `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` package, and created a target image under /opt/jessie_root, in this case for Jessie armhf. I also fixed all the links under this jessie_root image to be relative and not absolute.

I want to compile dynamic executables with the target rootfs libraries.

Initially I was compiling "fine" but I realized that I was linking to symbols on the host cross-toolchain libstdc++.

I'm using cmake, but for simplicity consider this commands:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ main.c
```

This will link to the host libstdc++ under `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/libstdc++.so`, **which is not desirable**.

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ main.cpp --sysroot=/opt/jessie_root -L=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

This will link correctly to the target libstdc++ under `/opt/jessie_root/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/libstdc++.so`, which I want.

The issue is that this seems a disaster waiting to happen, as if one of the default libs are not found on the target, the compiler will haply take one from the host cross-toolchain.

I could remove or rename them, but I don't want to mess on /usr/.

I have also played with GCC `-nostdlib` and LD `-nostdlib`, which seem to have different meanings. GCC `-nostdlib` is for libraries, and LD `-nostdlib` is for the search directories. LD `-nostdlib` have no effect, and GCC `-nostdlib` just forces me to specify the libraries manually, but it still keeps the search paths.

Naturally I could use another toolchain/compile my own, but I would prefer to stay on the packaged toolchain.

Comment: Do you have a toolchain file for CMake to specify the right settings for your target?
Why is your cross-compiler not within your tool chain folder? Is `/usr/bin/` the folder `make install` installed to? Or did you move the files?

Comment: Usually you simply specify a sysroot. Maybe something like `--sysroot=/opt/jessie_root`. In sysroot there would be `/opt/jessie_root/usr/include` with headers, and a `/opt/jessie_root/usr/lib` with libraries. Cmake adds a few wrinkles. You need to figure out how to get your sysroot into `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. In the regular world the compiler driver drives the linker so you don't have to worry about linker options and libraries. In the CMake world they invoke the linker themselves so you have to do things like select options and libraries.

Comment: As for the impending disaster, don't worry about it. If I am parsing things correctly, you won't be able to link a i686 library from the build machine with an armhf library for the target machine, so things will die early. You will know there is a problem. If you have only experienced the problem under Cmake, its probably because they don't use the compiler to drive link. Cmake invokes the linker directly, which kind of forces you to get the `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` right on your own. Cmake created a lot of problems for us on AIX and Solaris because of the practice.

Comment: The cross-toolchain is Ubuntu g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf package. If it doesn't find my target libraries it links against the toolchain ones. They are all armhf. I use a toolchain file with cmake, but I wanted to simplify it on how the compile and link call actually end up generated.

Comment: `if one of the default libs are not found on the target, the compiler will haply take one from the host cross-toolchain.` - What do you mean by "default" libraries? All libraries except `libstdc++` and some anothers should be specified **explicitely** in the command line for take an effect. Just care to pass libraries using their absolute paths. If libraries are searched by `find_library` or `find_package` CMake command, CMake has perfect means for restrict these commands with sysroot only.

Comment: "All libraries except libstdc++ and some anothers" is quite a lot: gcc, stdc++, c, atomic, pthread, m...do you even know the full list? is there a way to find it? That is the problem.